# Passing argument on SparkKubernetesOperator

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, airflow

I am using a spark with airflow, but not able to pass the arguments. I have tried multiple ways please suggest where right way to do this this.

dag.py file:

```
base_operator = SparkKubernetesOperator(
                application_file="spark-pi.yaml",
                task_id='segment_tag_refresh_process',
                namespace="spark-jobs", 
                api_group="sparkoperator.k8s.io",
                api_version="v1beta2",
                parms= {"ID": '1'},
                dag=dag
        )
```

spark-pi.yaml

```
apiVersion: sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
   name: spark-create-file
spec:
  type: Scala
  mode: cluster
  image: imagefilename
  imagePullSecrets:
    - sparkairlow
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  mainClass: org.apache.spark.examples.
  mainApplicationFile: local:///data/processing.py
  arguments: {{ parms.ID}}
  sparkVersion: 3.5.0
  sparkConf:
    spark.eventLog.enabled: "true"
    spark.eventLog.dir: /data/logs
  ....
  other configurations
  ....
```

While reading the arguments on processing.py I am using system arguments to read:

```
import sys
print("**********",sys.argv)
```

But not able to find the arguments.

If any think I'm missing please ask I'll update.

Comment: Hi @harshal-pagar can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using:

dag.py

```
dag = DAG('spark_application', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)

arguments_to_pass = {
    'id': '1'
}

spark_operator = SparkKubernetesOperator(
    task_id='spark_submit_task',
    namespace='your_namespace',  # Update with your Kubernetes namespace
    application_file="path/to/your/spark-application.yaml",
    kubernetes_conn_id='your_kubernetes_connection_id',
    params=arguments_to_pass,
    dag=dag,
)
```

spark-pi.yaml

```
# Your SparkApplication YAML file
apiVersion: sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: spark-create-file
spec:
  # other configurations...
  arguments: ["--id={{ params.id }}"]
```

reading the arguments on processing.py

```
import sys
print("**********",sys.argv)
```

Now it's working for me.